# How to enforce only one NULL value per unique combination of some other columns?

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-performance, unique-constraint

here's the situation, I have a table A with like such

```sql
CREATE TABLE A
(
    id         UUID    NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    B_id       bigint  NOT NULL,
    C_id       bigint  NOT NULL,
    some_value TIME,
    enabled    BOOLEAN NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT A_B_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (B_id) REFERENCES B (id),
    CONSTRAINT A_C_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (C_id) REFERENCES C (id)
);
```

And I want to have only one null value for `some_value` when `enabled` is false. Also, I want to ensure this null is for all foreign keys. So I can have x*y null values, but only one per couple of (x, y). I did something like this :

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_A_some_value
    ON A (B_id, C_id, (some_value IS NULL), (enabled IS FALSE))
    WHERE (some_value IS NULL);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_A_some_value
    ON A (B_id, C_id, (some_value IS NOT NULL), (enabled IS TRUE))
    WHERE (some_value IS NOT NULL);
```

Does it seems correct? Is there a better way? Also, performance is important in my case. Thanks

Edit:

I reworked the conditions and did something much more simpler:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_un_A
    ON A (B_id, C_type_id);

ALTER TABLE A
    ADD CONSTRAINT some_value_null_not_enabled
        CHECK ( (enabled IS FALSE AND some_value IS NULL) OR
                (enabled IS TRUE AND some_value IS NOT NULL));
```

Is it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this constraint:

```
 CHECK ( (enabled IS FALSE AND some_value IS NULL) OR
            (enabled IS TRUE AND some_value IS NOT NULL));
```

...the "enabled" column is redundant and simply means "some_value IS NOT NULL". If it is used in queries, it could be replaced with a generated column, or simply removed from the table.

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
    id         INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    B_id       INT NOT NULL,
    C_id       INT NOT NULL,
    t          TIME
--    ,enabled    BOOL NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS (t IS NOT NULL)
);
```

So, for each (B_id,C_id) you want at most one null value in column t. Note "enabled" is gone, which simplifies the situation.  You could do:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_A_null_t ON (B_id,C_id) WHERE t IS NULL;
```

Now, if "enabled" does something more than replicate "t is null" then you need both columns. This would be the case if there are rows where t is not null, and enabled is false. If what you want is: for each (B_id,C_id) at most one row with enabled=false and t is null, then:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_A_null_t ON (B_id,C_id) WHERE t IS NULL AND NOT enabled;
```

...and add a constraint saying t cannot be null if enabled is true.

Note, this doesn't seem related to the question:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_A_some_value
ON A (B_id, C_id, (some_value IS NOT NULL), (enabled IS TRUE))
WHERE (some_value IS NOT NULL);
```

Because this one means there can be at most one row with t not null for each value of (B_id,C_id), which doesn't sound like what you want.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to have only one null value for `some_value` when `enabled` is false.

A minimalist [partial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) unique index can do that:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX a_some_value_not_enabled_uni_idx ON a ((1))  -- constant
WHERE some_value IS NULL AND NOT enabled;
```

This index will hold at most one row.

> I want to ensure this null is for all foreign keys. So I can have x*y null values, but only one per couple of (x, y).

A partial [multicolumn](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX a_special_uni_idx ON a (a_id, b_id)
WHERE some_value IS NULL;
```

This allows each combination of `(a_id, b_id)` only once when `some_value` is null. Note that rows with NULL values in either `a_id` or `b_id` evade this restriction. See:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8289253/939860)

I **guess** you want to allow at most one NULL value in `some_value` per `(a_id, b_id)`.

I also guess your question is unclear.

Comment: the first code block is wrong? see demo[https://dbfiddle.uk/nGHaz1Y7]. aslo the following way works.`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX a_some_value_not_enabled_uni_idx ON a
    ((some_value IS NULL)) where NOT enabled;`

Comment: @jian: Yes, thanks, parentheses are required here.